# Very Simple Regex

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression which will ignore the sentence containing "XYZ" character.
I am using this but this is not working

```
<td>(.+[^XYZ])</td>
```

Comment: How are you matching sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match a **line** not containing the string "XYZ" you can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?:(?!XYZ).)*$
```

If you just want to check that the line doesn't contain any of those characters in any position, use a negative character class:

```
^[^XYZ]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

"(.+[^XYZ])" means "at least one character followed by neither X,Y,Z.

Matching anything that doesn't contain X,Y,Z works with "([^XYZ]*)", or "([^XYZ]+)" if you want want empty matches.